# is there an attractively themed Drupal app (kinda like Joomla) with at least hello-world implementation of lots of hooks for learning purposes?

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming

Joomla looks pretty good out of the box. Drupal looks very ugly out of the box and does not do anything, except for admin tasks.

Is there by any chance a n00b-friendly Drupal app that would look pretty (kind of like Joomla out of the box) and use a whole bunch of hooks so that I could see them in action in a relatively big app?

ETA: ok, let me ask a more specific question from the same area. Is there a Drupal distro/app that would have the same basic functionality and look-and-feel as out of the box Joomla? While I personally might not know enough about what functionality and look-and-feel would be perfect for n00bs, the popularity of Joomla suggests that it can be thought of as a decent first approximation. Conversely, the widespread n00b unhappiness with out of the box Drupal suggests that it's not a good approximation to that at all.

Comment: What version of Drupal are you interested in learning?

Answer (score 2):

What about a customized Drupal distribution?

- [Managing News](http://managingnews.com/)
- [Open Atrium](http://openatrium.com/)
- [Open Publish](http://openpublishapp.com/)
- [Pressflow](https://launchpad.net/pressflow)

If you don't like how Drupal looks, you could always install a [new theme](http://drupal.org/project/Themes).

Comment: I agree that some of them are nicely themed. But clearly they are even more elaborate and complex than the original Drupal distro, so they do not look like an answer to the question "how can I learn Drupal basics with a minimum effort?"

Comment: If the goal is to learn Drupal without any effort but have it looks good and fancy, you are not learning Drupal. Learning Drupal requires efforts.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a nice looking Drupal App then you can try OpenAtrium (http://openatrium.com/). It's pretty cool. It's code is perhaps not for the beginner, but it shows how good Drupal can look and act!

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the Examples modules - http://drupal.org/project/examples. You can learn a lot from these, but obviously they are no good looking Apps, just API examples.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the core Drupal modules (User module for example would be a good start)